# Is it possible to change the status of a sprint by jrjc?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

I have to set all active sprints to "closed" by a scheduled job every night. 
Is it possible to achieve this by using the java rest client in any way ?
Any hints are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[JRCJ](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client) does not seem to contain a client for the JIRA Software REST API, but you can easily write something yourself because the appropriate REST resources are available.

There are REST resources to retrieve boards and sprints:

- [GET /rest/agile/1.0/board](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board-getAllBoards)
- [GET /rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board/%7BboardId%7D/sprint)

And there is a REST resource to update (close) a sprint:

- [POST /rest/agile/1.0/sprint/{sprintId}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/sprint-partiallyUpdateSprint)